# Pass php variable/array data to angular js

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I am using php database connectivity with "$row" as an array that stores name as a field in it .But after lots of searching i dint get how to pass php variable in angular js 
here's the code ,I am trying to achieve.how is it possible i am new to this your help will be appreciated.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','practice');

if (!$con) {
    die("couldnt connect". mysqli_error);
}

$q= "select * from test";
$result= $con->query($q);

if ($result->num_rows>0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row['name']."<br>";

    }
}

print_r($result);

echo json_encode($result);

?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js">
</head>
<body>

<ul ng-init="names = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row)); ?>">
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
   <p>{{x.name}}</p>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script needs some serous tidy up, your are echoing/printing lots of stuff before even your html starts. if there are purely to test your DB outcome then why to mix them the with  **<br>** tags. anyway what is the out put of `echo $row['name']."<br>";`? when you check the page source will you see any data from the db? change that line to `print_r($row['name']);` and let me know if the data is fetched and printed (on your html page source) then we will get into solving the problem :)

Comment: no @ali it is all fine with database output $row['name'] is perfectly fetching the data but problem is with js how can i show that array data of $row['name'] in angular js

Comment: ok cool, next thing will be including the angular js script, something like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js">`

Comment: yeah my mistake SORRY but still its showing this "[]" only as a output @Ali

Comment: whats the value of `<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row)); ?>` ?

Comment: I mean what you have in your page source if you replace the above line in this `<ul ng-init="names = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row)); ?>">`

Comment: p.s. you might want to update your smple code with included angular js script to prevent other users confusion :)

Comment: $row is display the output as " eden frank matt". but in angular js output is "[]" only. @Ali

Comment: so then thats another problem, in your loop you are addressing a filed named **name* which is not exists in your data collection, ill explain this bit in an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your php code needs a bit of improvement use this instead of that:

```
$arr = array();
if ($result->num_rows>0) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$arr[] = $row['name'] ;

}
}
```

Then echo it as

```
<ul ng-init="names = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr)); ?>">
```

Comment: Yeah that was quiet easy . Thanks for pointing out the error it helped alot thanks

Answer (score 1):

As discussed  earlier, you need to format your data in the **names**'s to;

1. be a valid valid JSON
2. provide a field **name** since you are seeking it in your loop **(ng-repeat)**

So at the moment the value assigned to your "names" is "eden frank matt" as you mentioned in your comment. this needs to be changed to something like:

```
[
    {name: 'eden'},
    {frank: 'eden'},
    {matt: 'eden'}
]
```

so when you check the **html source** we should have a collection of lets say "people" and then going through all of its element and point to their field "name" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js">
    </script>
</head>


<body ng-app>

<ul ng-init="people = [{name:'eden'}, {name:'frank'}, {name:'matt'}]">
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
        <p>{{person.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this that's the basic thing but if i get a lot of database in an array with lots of fields in it then php database connection is required and then convert it into angular js array will show up that data. I want to achieve php with angular js . i know i can do this in php alone . but its mandatory in my project

Comment: i didn't suggest to write the JSON manually @Sharefun. you have to pars your result from the database in a way to be a vlid JSON with the fields your going to look for them further on. the example in my answer is when you are looking into the HTML source in the browser  and not your code

Comment: i've asked you what you see when you check the html source (in the browser i meant) . so again, when you open your page in a web browser, when you view the source (in the web browser) what will you see instead of `<ul ng-init="names = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row)); ?>">` ? it should be `<ul ng-init="names = .....">` .which the (**.....**) is the bit whoch I'm interested to know :)

Comment: Okay @Ali that's fine . but their is another way i can choose may be like using $http.get() and success function to this i dont know how use i am new to angular js and cant find any exact solution for this . If you know then please tell me.

Comment: okay it shows "null" it means nothing is coming up in $row but php is showing the data but as i pass this to angular js it shows null . I MUST HAVE DOING SOMETHING WRONG . cant figure it out.

Comment: I think your problem is not with Angular JS , the issue is how to assemble the right data structure to pass it your tiny loop. it doesn't matter what is the source of your collection, it can be direct call to the DB or an Ajax call to a server, anyway you have to make sure those two points I mentioned in my answer are satisfied **a.** valid **JSON** format and **b.** each item have a field **name**, good luck :)

Comment: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php" check out this link this is the php data formatted to json then we can simply fetch in angular js se this "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_mysql" but problem how is that data converted to json code

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement, and the below worked for me.

```
data-ng-click="editField(product, '<?php echo $_SESSION["login_user"] ?>')"
```